# transmission fluid low reading

Tags: transmission, isuzu

Vehicle: 2004 isuzu crosswind 2.5 liter 4JA1 engine

When I check my transmission fluid level while engine is not running it sits perfectly on the 'C' level. But when I check it while the engine is running and I run the transmission through all its gears it doesn't even reach the dipstick. Is this normal? Also I'm feeling the symptoms of having a low transmission fluid level.

Additionally, up to what level should I add more fluid if in case I need to.

Answer (score 2):

Without year make model and engine size I can't give you the exact procedure. But on most all transmissions with a dipstick, the transmission fluid levels should be checked with the vehicle warmed up to operating temperature, then add as needed. You should have info on this in your owners manual. If it is indeed low, you may have to address a leak. If there are spots of transmission fluid on the floor under the vehicle or an inspection reveals leakage, it will need addressed. Transmission fluid does not evaporate. It gets too low from leakage.

Comment: oh my bad i forgot to put in the details

its a 2004 isuzu crosswind 2.5 liter 4JA1 engine

Comment: I've updated the question with the OPs information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , it is normal for oil level on dip stick to be higher when the engine is off. When the engine on ,the transmission fills the torque converter/fluid couplings . Any transmission I have had since my 1941 Hydromatic required the oil level to be checked with the engine running . What does your owner manual say ? Presumably you have a leak - leak stop products are more likely to cause damage than fix the leak.

Comment: so based on what the measurement is during operating temperature, does it mean i am low on fluid? thank you for your response

Comment: yes...............